# What is the compositum product module $MN$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, commutative-algebra, modules, algebraic-number-theory

> Proposition 5. Let $A$ be a ring contained in a field $L$. Let $В$ be the set
>   of elements of $L$ which are integral over $A$. Then $В$ is a ring, called
>   the  integral closure of $A$ in $L$.
>
> *Proof.* Let $x, у$ lie in $B$, and let $M,N$ be two finitely generated $A$-  modules such that $xM \subset M$ and $yN \subset N$.
>   Then $MN$ is finitely generated,  and is mapped into itself by
>   multiplication with $x \pm у$ and $xy$.

I forgot what $MN$ is defined as...

Comment: It is the set of all elementwise products $mn$ (built in $A$) for $m  \in M$, and $n  \in N$. Just a matter of notation.

Comment: @dan_fulea how is $M \subset A$?

Comment: @dan_fulea oh shit, I see now.  $M \subset L$ a field in which we take the integral closure.

Comment: Oh, typed to quickly, without reading carefully. The proof is taken from somewhere, is the proof finished, what are $M,N$ explicitly? I suppose that $MN$ is the set of all finite sums of products of the shape $mn$... taken in $L$. ($M,N$ should be included in $L$ at least...)